# Getting data from google play with C# HttpWebRequest and it's response unlike browser

Tags: c#, google-play, httpwebrequest

I try to getting data from google play web page with C# HttpWebRequest but when it's response I got difference result

Code:

```
public const string googlePlayUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";

public void GetData(string packageName) {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(googlePlayUrl + packageName));
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    request.ContentType = "text/html";
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0";
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    request.BeginGetResponse((IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) =>
    {
        HttpWebRequest requested = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)requested.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
        {
            System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
            responseStream.Close();
        }
    }, request);
}
```

Request connection is fine, I got response but it's difference than when I access the web-page with browser. It's no elements that I want to use such as

- div.id-app-title
- span attr[itemprop="genre"]
- div attr[itemprop="description"]

Not sure why, I've try to set its user-agent but it still not work or maybe I set it wrong.
Wish someone have solution for that :)

Comment: So... What are you saying exactly? You're not receiving the same HTML when you access it via a browser, as when you download it using a HttpWebRequest?

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard Yes

Comment: Have you tried comparing the two results, seeing what's different about them?

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard Tried, Too many things are different it's hard to compare but as I was said that the fields that I want does not exists when make request with HttpWebRequest. When I request with HttpWebRequest I saw </html> It's seems to be fine ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your public IP address has not been blocked by Google, you can use the synchronous method `request.GetResponse()` together with the `Parallel.ForEach()` as shown below:

```
public static string GetDataSync(string packageName)
{
    string result = "";

    Uri uri = new Uri(googlePlayUrl + packageName);

    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    var response = request.GetResponse();

    var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        result = (reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    responseStream.Close();

    return result;
}
```

Call the method above using `Parallel.ForEach` and a tread-safe collection `ConcurrentDictionary` to store the html string result per package:

```
IEnumerable<string> appPackages = new List<string>() {
    "com.google.android.apps.youtube.music",
    "com.netflix.mediaclient"
};

ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> results = 
   new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(Environment.ProcessorCount, appPackages.Count());

Parallel.ForEach(appPackages, (app) =>
{
    results.TryAdd(app, GetDataSync(app));
});
```